# How to access "request payload" in Koa web-framework?

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-bodyparser

We are using navigator.sendBeacon function to send data to Koa server, in which we are using bodyparser.

If we not wrapped data into form then by default this function send data as request payload. How I can able to access this data on Koa server?

Example -

```
navigator.sendBeacon('http://localhost:3000/cookies/', 'test=payload')
```

At server, request body is blank.

[image]

Comment: see `enableTypes` option for `koa-bodyparser`.

Answer (score 5):

Considering that

1. Koa does not parse request body, so you need to use either [koa-bodyparser](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser) or [koa-body](https://github.com/dlau/koa-body),
2. `koa-bodyparser` by default has only `json` and `form` parsing enabled,
3. From [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n5Sv.png), it is clear that `navigator.sendBeacon` set the `Content-Type` to `text`,

You need to change the Koa server code, so that it parses `text` data.

Example:

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
  bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser'),
  app = (module.exports = new Koa());

app.use(bodyParser({ enableTypes: ['json', 'text'] }));

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  // ctx.request.body should contain the parsed data.
  console.log('Received data:', ctx.request.body);
  ctx.body = ctx.request.body;
});

if (!module.parent) app.listen(3000);
```

Tested with

koa `2.7.0`,

koa-bodyparser `4.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Although `koa` doesn't parse `request` body and for some reason you don't want to use `koa-bodyparser` you can still use the raw `http` to collect the `body` from `request` object.

```
app.use(async (ctx) => {  
  try {
    // notice that I'm wrapping event emitter in a `promise`
    ctx.body = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = '';
        // this is same as your raw `http.request.on('data', () => ()`
        ctx.req.on('data', chunk => {
          data += chunk;
        };
        ctx.req.on('error', err => {
          reject(err);
        };
        ctx.req.on('end', () => {
          resolve(data);
        };
      });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```